# How to ignore already translated strings from Django's .po files when running `django-admin makemessages`

Tags: django, internationalization

My Django app uses some strings that are already translated in Django. In custom templates for password reset process I'd like to use some of the original texts, like [this one prompting user to log in](https://www.transifex.com/django/django/viewstrings/#sk/contrib-admin/12374941) after completing the reset process.

Custom template contains `<p>{% trans "Your password has been set.  You may go ahead and log in now." %}</p>` taken directly from the [original form file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_complete.html#L16).

After running `django-admin makemessages` my .po file contains this:

```
#: core/templates/auth/password-reset-complete.html:10
msgid "Your password has been set.  You may go ahead and log in now."
msgstr ""
```

Translation is working, rendered page already contains the correct translated string. **Is it possible to ommit this empty translation from .po file automatically?** Simply removing it will only work until I run `makemessages` again. It's already been translated, to duplicate it in my .po file seems unnecessary.

Comment: did you tried to mark string as fuzzy `#, fuzzy`

Comment: @latsha Maybe I was not clear in my question. I'd like them removed. Not be in my .po file. Marking them fuzzy will not remove them from my file. Seems to me like an unnecessary duplication. They've been already translated, I don't want to copy those to my files (where I'd have to mark which strings are the exact copies, so translators don't have to translate them, or maintain a translation myself, neither of which I want to do).

Comment: @MartinTóth have you found a solution?

Comment: @MaxMalysh I have not, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you found something now? :)

Comment: @PhilippS. Nope :( I'm adding "# Translators:" comments to each occurrence so when translating, at least there's a warning that the translation should remain empty on purpose. Solution from Ove's anwser may be worth trying out, but I haven't found enough time to actually implement it in a "production" project.

Answer (score 5):

You can try putting your string into a variable before giving it to `trans`, so that `makemessages` doesn't notice it. Something like

```
{% with mystr="Your password has been set.  You may go ahead and log in now." %}
{% trans mystr %}
{% endwith %}
```

Alternatively, you could create your own custom template tag that simply calls `gettext` (from `django.utils.translation`) on its argument, and use that instead of `trans`.

Comment: How would you write this custom template tag?

Answer (score 0):

Using @Ove idea, I used two wrapped tags `trans_done` and `blocktrans_done`:

`templatetags/i18n_done.py`

```py
from django import template
from django.templatetags.i18n import (
    do_block_translate,
    do_translate,
)

register = template.Library()


@register.tag("translate_done")
@register.tag("trans_done")
def translate_done(parser, token):
    return do_translate(parser, token)


@register.tag("blocktranslate_done")
@register.tag("blocktrans_done")
def block_translate_done(parser, token):
    return do_block_translate(parser, token)
```

Then in my template, I simply:

```html
{% load i18n_done %}
<p>{% trans_done "Your password has been set.  You may go ahead and log in now." %}</p>
```

This will still be translated, but gettext will not find those strings.

Simple enough ;-)